# windows phone call method crash

Tags: vb.net, windows-phone-8

I'm making a contact page in an app with the ability to call at the helpdesk, if the user push on a hyperlink with the telephone number shown on. I found some code, but if I run it, the app crashes an I get a debugger.break.

**Here's my code:**

```
Private Sub Telefoonnummer_Click(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs)

        Dim phoneCallTask As PhoneCallTask = New PhoneCallTask()

        phoneCallTask.PhoneNumber = "0473352787"
        phoneCallTask.DisplayName = "Aramark helpdesk"

        phoneCallTask.Show()

    End Sub
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did it give you an error message? Have you seen the Remarks section of [PhoneCallTask Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.tasks.phonecalltask)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can happen if ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER capability is not enabled in [WMAppManifest.xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206936%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)